# Convert image's bit depth with PyPng

Tags: python

Ok, so I just started python and I need to convert an image to 4bpp for a tool, and I came across pypng, but I couldn't find how to only convert to a bit depth of 4, so this is my result from looking at a few dozen examples:

```
import png
import numpy as np

with open("temporarypng.png", 'wb') as f:
        w_depth = png.Writer(im.shape[1], im.shape[0], bitdepth=16)
        im_uint16 = np.round(im).astype(np.uint16)
        w_depth.write(f, np.reshape(im_uint16, (-1, im.shape[1])))
f.close()
```

Unsurprisingly, it doesn't work. Could anyone help me?

Comment: BTW: if you use `with open() as f:` then you don't need `f.close()` because `with` closes it automatically.

Comment: to create `4bpp` you would use `bitdepth=4` and probably `uint8`. To create color image it may need `palette=[(R,G,B),...]` with 16 colors.

Comment: you have to create image array with values `0..15` (for greyscale image) and with palette `[(r,g,b),...]` with 16 values (for color image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `4bpp` then you should use `bitdepth=4` and you have to create `array` with values `0..15` (for greyscale image) and also array with 16 values `(R,G,B)` for `palette` (for color image)

I use `PIL` to load `RGB` image and convert to image with 16 colors/indexes to palette with 16 colors (`RGB`)

```
import png
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('zima-400x300.jpg')

# convert RGB to 16 colors
image = image.quantize(16)

# get palette as flat list [r, g, b, r, g, b, ...]
palette = image.getpalette()
# conver flat list to tupled [(r, g, b), (r, g, b), ...]
palette = [tuple(palette[x:x+3]) for x in range(0, len(palette), 3)]
#print(len(palette))
palette = palette[:16]
print(palette)

# get pixels/indexes as numpy array
im = np.array(image)
print(im)

with open('png-4bpp.png', 'wb') as f:
    #png_writer = png.Writer(im.shape[1], im.shape[0], bitdepth=4)  # without palette
    png_writer = png.Writer(im.shape[1], im.shape[0], bitdepth=4, palette=palette)  # with palette
    png_writer.write(f, im)
```

Input `RGB` image

[image]

Ouput `4bpp` with palette

[image]

Ouput `4bpp` without palette

[image]